# Output Date Without Slashes

Tags: c#

I need to create a file that has today's date in the file name.  How can I get the date just as `20111110` and no slashes?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Also, you may not be be aware of [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx). It makes building paths a little cleaner and more foolproof.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use a [custom datetime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: what if I want to read the date without any slashes directly from the json file, and then convert it to date as above given answer??

Answer (score 7):

how about something like this:

```
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
string fname = file.Name.Remove((file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length));
fname = fname + Now.ToString("_MMddyyyy_HHmmss") + file.Extension;
```

This creates the filename with the embedded datetime.  Then you can prepend you folder path and pass it to SaveAs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
  string s = d.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Sorry for necro but, is there any reason not to just do `string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");`?

Comment: No reason not to.  I was probably just being verbose.